# '(0, _reactRedux.connect)(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)' is an instance of Object)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

[If you need more fragments of code, I'm happy to show you]
I'm just getting myself into Redux with React Native and I was building a really basic store: it just reads and adds data. I'm facing this problem where I can connect a component with `mapStateToProps` but when I want to use `mapDispatchToProps` it throws this TypeError: `(0, _reactRedux.connect)(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactRedux.connect)(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp)', '(0, _reactRedux.connect)(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)' is an instance of Object)`

This is how I'm using and importing connect

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp);
```

These are my `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and the connect:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => state;
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addQuote: (val) => dispatch(addQuote(val))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp);
```

This is my reducer file

```js
const initialState = []

const ADD_QUOTE = 'ADD_QUOTE';

export const addQuote = val => ({
    type: ADD_QUOTE,
    payload: {
        quote: val
    }
});

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_QUOTE:
            return [action.payload].concat(state)
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm using the action creator

```js
const handleSubmitButton = (val) => addQuote(val);
<TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.submitButton}
                onPress={ () => handleSubmitButton(quoteForm) }
            >
                <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                    SOUMETTRE
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I appreciate any kind of help, since I'm new to this topic and from what I know I'm doing ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered on Reactiflux, the issue was a malformed call to `connect`:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp);
```

`mapDispatch` needs to be the second arg, not a separate function call:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp);
```